# how to make text vertically center in fabric js TextBox

Tags: textbox, height, fabricjs

I am working on one fabric js editor, in which I need to implement TextBox as a Button look and feel,

For that, I Have implemented `TextBox` with `Background`, But Problem is that Height of `TextBox`.

I am trying this kind of code :

```
var text = new fabric.Textbox("this is text", {
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  width: 300,
  height: 500,
  fill: 'red'
})
canvas.add(text);
```

Now my `Textbox` is rendered of `width: 300` but `height` is not rendered. how can I set Height to My `TextBox`

And another Thing, when I set `Height` to `TextBox`, I need to keep text in `Center` of height **(vertical center)**

what should I do, I can't understand, how to override default **fabtic.Textbox** class.

Please help me, If any one have Any suggestion.